# What are the best methods for propagating Alocasias?

Tags: houseplants, propagation, alocasia

Recently I added some *Alocasias* to my collection of indoor plants. I got two stingrays and they came in pretty bad shape with root rot.
One survived.

Can you snap a leaf off and propagate it in water or do you need to separate out the pups?

What have people found to be the best methods?

Answer (score 1):

*Alocasias* are growing from bulbs or rhizomes so the best is to use root division or in this case rhizome division.

Effectively this means separating the pups from a mother plant or dividing a large plant into two or more individual plants depending on the structure and size of the rhizomes.

Here is an article about it: H[ow To Propagate Alocasia – Tips On Alocasia Plant Propagation](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/alocasia-plant/alocasia-plant-propagation.htm).